# Javascript mobile redirect not working on android devices

Tags: javascript, android

I've made a script which should redirect a mobile user to another domain if the site is directly accessed from a mobile device. However if the user has been referred from that domain, they should stay on the page ("View main site").

The reason it has been done like this instead of a server side language is because I don't have access to the server side files, but they have agreed to put in a javascript include.

This code works fine on ios and windows mobile devices, though not android.

Any ideas?

```
var referrer = 'http://m.example.com/'; // The referring url
var isMobile={
    Android:function(){
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    },
    BlackBerry:function(){
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    },
    iOS:function(){
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)
    },
    Opera:function(){
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)
    },
    Windows:function(){
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
    },
    any:function(){
        return(isMobile.Android()||isMobile.BlackBerry()||isMobile.iOS()||isMobile.Opera()||isMobile.Windows())
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
    var url=referrer;
    if(document.referrer.toString()===url){// If the referrer is the same as the url set the cookie
        document.cookie="mobile=1";
    }
    var coo=new Array();
    coo=document.cookie.split(';');
    var stay=0;
    if(isMobile.any()){
        for(i in coo){
            var cookie=coo[i].split('=');
            if(cookie[0].valueOf()==="mobile"){
                stay=1;
            }
        }
        if(stay===0){
            window.location=url;// if the cookie hasn't been set redirect to the referring url
        }
    }
}
```